# Unexpected column width change when adding image as column contnet

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am having a table with 3 columns, each with percentage defined column width: 55%, 5%, 40%.

When I insert text only it works fine. But when I insert an img or table in the first column, the width of the first column change (In my case, it is shorter than 55%) even though the tr row's length is stil the same.

I have tried reproducing the error here but I can't [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b58oum8s/6/). It is something like this (but this version works):

```
    <div style="width: 100%">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">hello world</td>
        <td class="col2">hello world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</td>
        <td class="col2">hello world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1"><img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01553/nestle_1553096c.jpg"/></td>
        <td class="col2">Hello world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <table class="table-evidence">
                <thead><tr><td>Pros</td><td>Cons</td></tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr><td>Milk is good</td><td>Cruel to squeeze milk from cow</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Butter is good</td><td>Bloody fat</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </td>
        <td class="col2">Hello world</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And the Css:

```
.table, .table tr, .table td {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;  
    width: 100%;
}

.table .col1 {
    width: 60%;
}
.table .col1 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.table .col2 {
    width: 40%;
}
```

It would be great if you can give me some hints on where it can go wrong. Thanks very much.

Comment: try adding `table-layout: fixed;` for `table`

Answer (score 0):

As Vitorino says, if you add this to your css it should fix it.

```
table.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

See this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_table-layout